# polyfit line coordinates - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I calculated a line based on two points, how can I store all the line coordinates (x and y) in two separated arrays?

Script:

```
x1=50;
x2=130;
y1=30;
y2=200;
coefficients = polyfit([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 1);
a = coefficients (1);
b = coefficients (2);
plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2],  'b','LineWidth',2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about *polyval*. You ca generate the points as shown in the below code:

```
x1=50;
x2=130;
y1=30;
y2=200;
p = polyfit([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 1);

N = 100 ;  % can be changed 
xi = linspace(x1,x2,N) ;
yi = polyval(p,xi) ;

plot(xi,yi,'.-r')
```

Alternatively you can also use slope/ intercept obtained from *polyfit* to get the coordinates.

```
x1=50;
x2=130;
y1=30;
y2=200;
p = polyfit([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 1);

N = 100 ;  % can be changed 
xi = linspace(x1,x2,N) ;
yi = p(2)+p(1)*xi ;
plot(xi,yi,'.-r')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two points, (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), you can directly obtain the line coordinates by slicing:

```
n = 100;
xx=x1:(x2-x1)/n:x2
yy=y1:(y2-y1)/n:y2
```

Where `n` specifies how many points of coordinate.  `xx` and `yy` are two arrays storing and coordinates on the line.

You can also plot the line by

```
plot(xx,yy)
```